# How to parallelize table loading in pyspark from Cassandra

Tags: python, apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark

I have a pyspark job which has 5 table loading statements one after the others.Table loading is happening sequential.How can i load all 5 tables at a time.

Comment: code please to see what's happening

Comment: use threading in python

Comment: What are you going to achieve? Why do you need load this tables in parallel? For increasing performance and utilization of several cores?

Comment: Increasing performance

Comment: I am writing code in pyspark. Loading of table itself consuming 50s of total job.I need to reduce it.